# no viable alternative at input : Siddhi Query

Tags: import, siddhi, wso2-cep

I am trying to write a simple siddhi query by simply importing a custom mapped stream. But as soon as I import stream and validate query, it gives error.

My complete query however is

```
@Import('bro.in.ssh.log:1.0.0')
define stream inStream (ts string, uid string, id.orig_h string, id.orig_p int, id.resp_h string, id.resp_p int, version int, client string, server string, cipher_alg string, mac_alg string, compression_alg string, kex_alg string, host_key_alg string, host_key string);

@Export('bro.out.ssh.log:1.0.0')
define stream outStream (ts string, ssh_logins int);

from inStream
select dateFormat (ts,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') as formatedTs, count
group by formatedTs
insert into outStream;
```

All I want is to count number of records in a log for a single minute and export time and count to an output Stream. But I am getting errors even at the very first line.
My input is a log file of `bro` ids, `ssh.log`. Its sample record would be something like:
             `{"ts":"2016-05-08T08:59:47.363764Z","uid":"CLuCgz3HHzG7LpLwH9","id.orig_h":"172.30.26.119","id.orig_p":51976,"id.resp_h":"172.30.26.160","id.resp_p":22,"version":2,"client":"SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.0","server":"SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6","cipher_alg":"arcfour256","mac_alg":"hmac-md5","compression_alg":"none","kex_alg":"diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1","host_key_alg":"ssh rsa","host_key":"8d:df:71:ac:29:1f:67:6f:f3:dd:c3:e5:2e:5f:3e:b4"}`

Comment: Please provide a sample input also

Comment: I have added an input record but this error occurs regardless of any input. I am just writing the query for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siddhi does not allow an Attribute name to have dot ('.') character. So please edit the Event Stream such that the Attribute names (such as `id.orig_h`) will not have the Dot character.